# Macvim CSS/Sass syntax highlighting error when using asterisk + slash

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using a Compass sprite @import statement in my Sass stylesheet which includes all of the PNG files in a directory (`@import 'place-detail-icons/*.png';`). Problem is that Macvim sees everything after the `/*` as a CSS comment, and so it displays the rest of the stylesheet as a comment.

I was able to fix this by putting `/**/` on the line below the @import statement in order to fake out Macvim. But was wondering if anyone's found a non-hack way to address this. Here's a larger selection of the code.

```
@import 'mixins/tabs';
@import 'mixins/timestamps';
@import 'mixins/triangles';
@import 'place-detail-icons/*.png';

  #modal .file-upload {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  #details {
    position: relative;
    left: -160px;
    width: 1280px;
    min-height: 410px;
    padding: 30px 0 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid $white;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the CSS syntax file. If you look in `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/css.vim` on line 179 you'll see this:

```
syn region cssInclude start="@import" end=";" contains=cssComment,cssURL,cssUnicodeEscape,cssMediaType
```

If you remove the `cssComment` from the `contains=` it will fix it; however, editing the built-in syntax files directly is not advised because your changes will be overwritten when you upgrade vim. Instead, open the file and `:sav! ~/.vim/syntax/css.vim` to create a duplicate that will override the built-in syntax first and edit that.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I created the new file and edited w/ no effect, then tried editing the original with no luck, syntax is still wrong in MacVim and Vim.

Comment: You need to save the file and then `set ft=css` again or reopen the CSS file. It's working for me.

Comment: And in order to make this solution work for Sass files, go through the same process above except open `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sass.vim`, then save and edit `~/.vim/syntax/sass.vim` on or around line 56. Thanks Connor.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can put this into your `~/.vimrc` file: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.scss setfiletype sass`
Vim will use the Sass syntax with *.scss files.